# Любое количество любых символов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как, используя регулярные выражения задать паттерн вида :

`Начало` `...` `конец` ,

где `...` это любые символы включая пробелы, тире подчеркивания и целые числа причем сколько их неизвестно. Я пытаюсь сделать это так :

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"Start:\S*\s*End");
```

т.к. `\S*` - ноль или более символов не яв-ся пробелом а 
`\s*` - ноль или более символов являющихся. Однако это неправильно. Как исправить ?

Comment: `^Start:.*End$` - так попробуйте. `.` - любой символ. Квантификаторы `^` и `$` - начало и конец строки, соответственно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я наверно неправильно описал проблему. Дело в том, что строка одна и в этой строке несколько раз встречается этот паттерн. Ваш вариант пернет 1 совпедение - а именно начальную строку.

Comment: А задача в чем состоит? Выбрать части заключенные между `Start:` и `End`? Ааа, вам нужен ленивый квантификатор :) Ну да, вам подойдет ответ Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"Start:.*?End", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Подробности**

- `Start:` - начальный разделитель
- `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше (`*?` — ленивый квантификатор)
- `End` - конечный разделитель
- `RegexOptions.Singleline` - флаг, благодаря которому `.` находит все символы, даже символы перевода строки.

Сининимические конструкции:

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"(?s)Start:.*?End");
var pattern = new Regex(@"Start:(?s:.*?)End");
```

Однако, если необходимо найти подстроку, в которой не должно быть разделителей, нужно использовать "умеренно жадный токен"
 (`tempered greedy token`):

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"(?s)Start:(?:(?!Start:).)*?End");
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Этот шаблон в строке `Start: 1, Start: 2, End: 56` найдет `Start: 2, End`, а не `Start: 1, Start: 2, End`.