# Поиск слова в тексте и удаление ненужных слов c#

Tags: c#, поиск, текст

В общем есть строка n-й длины (Текст от 5 до 1000 слов).

Пример текста: "В языках программирования и теории типов полиморфизмом называется способность функции обрабатывать данные разных типов. Существует несколько разновидностей полиморфизма. Две наиболее различных из них были описаны Кристофером Стрэчи в 1967 году. .... Статья от **18 марта 2018 г.** Дальше тоже может быть любой текст."

Нужно написать программу которая найдет дату **"18 марта 2018 г."** и удалит с текста абсолютно все кроме этой даты. Для помощи в поиске даты: Нужная дата всегда начинается со слова "от" **(Пример: от 18 марта 2018 г.).** Если в тексте встречаются даты в таком же формате, но дата не начинается со слова "от", то их нужно также удалить как и весь остальной текст.

Расскажите и покажите как это можно сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Пока что получилось удалить все символы до даты, а как дальше?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = "привет мир как дела от 12 мая 2018 г. бла бла бла";
            var strIndex = str.IndexOf("от");
            str = str.Remove(0, strIndex + 3);
            Console.WriteLine(asd);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Дальше пытался удалить так, но оно не работает:

```
strLen = str.Length();
strIndex = str.IndexOf("г.");
str.Remove(strIndex + 2, strLen);
```

Comment: В первую очередь формализуйте все возможные форматы даты.

Comment: IndexOf() и Substring() - знание двух этих функций поможет решить данную задачу.

Comment: @Shpunder с помощью IndexOf() удалил все что было до даты, дальше не получается.

Comment: @Sanvirtus так Вы дальше ничего и не делаете

Comment: @Igor я просто код не писал неудачных попыток. Добавил для вас что бы вы видели что я пытался сделать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/822676/218063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "привет мир как дела от 12 мая 2018 г. бла бла бла";
string result = "";
string[] parts = str.Split(new string[] { "от" });
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
  int indexYear = parts[i].IndexOf("г.");
  if (indexYear == -1)
  {
    result = result + parts[i];
  } 
  else
  {
    result = result + parts[i].Substring(0, indexYear + 2);
  }
}
```

Добавьте мелочи, типа отрезания начала строки до первого "от" до деления ее на части, удаления пробелов вокруг даты и т.п.