# Любое количество любых символов в notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, шаблоны, notepad++

Необходимо задать следующую строку

```
"='root' && ... ="
```

где ... - любое количество любых символов

Как задать любое количество любых символов в регулярном выражении? Видел

[Любое количество любых символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822676/%d0%9b%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Запросы приведенные в ответе

```
(?s)"='root' && .*? ="
"='root' && (?s:.*?) ="
```

не помогают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прошу не минусовать за то что пишу не в комментарии (а привести ссылку как в документ вставлять комментарий с картинкой)

Между символом `=` и словом `root` не должно быть пробелов - в этом случае между `root` и символом `=` не должно быть никаких директив, а если есть, то прошу 
пояснить значение следующих участков кода

1. `\s*` (есть сомнения в необходимости использования этой директивы перед `root` , если пробел есть, то почему не использовать `\s+` )
2. `\s+` (Как я понял `\s+` означает пробел, а вот что `\s*` не понял.)

Понимание использования `\s*` мешает составлению следующей команды

3. `if ...== 'root' && ...==`

Еще забыл как использовать апострофы в запросе поискового выражения - нужно ли обрамлять апострофы специальным образом?

Извините что расспрашиваю вас а не гугл - просто во многих местах непонятно написано.

Comment: Там надо галочку поставить в поле *и новые строки*

Comment: `*` или `+` - это квантификаторы, звездочка означает 0 и более символов, а плюс 1 и более символов, т.е. при звездочке объявляется неявное появление пробельных символов, `\s` - это не только пробелы, это все пробельные символы, такие как табуляция, перевод строки. Эквивалентом строки `\s` будет `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`. Но самой сути вопроса я честно говоря не уловил, приведите примеры что вы хотите получить и из каких данных, наверное будет проще.

Comment: Да сколько можно то старые вопросы поднимать))) автор уже не вернется скорее всего, последнее посещение 12 дек '19 в 21:02, а я как обычно...

Answer (score 2):

Любое количество любых символов задаётся вот так вот:

```
[\s\S]*
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/1Sq61J/1

Comment: что эквивалентно `.*`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, замените по ссылке регулярку на `.*`. Только если флаг `s` поставить

Comment: `.*` без галочки и новые строки (эквивалент single line) не будет захватывать перевод строки, но перевод строки входит в группу `\s` поэтому будет выбран.

Comment: @PotroNik не понял комментарий, если честно. Какой галочки? Или вы aleksandrbarakin пишете?

Comment: @dIm0n это был более общий комментарий, почему `.*` не всегда эквивалента `[\s\S]*` включил single line режим подстановки шаблона в вашем примере и поменял на `.*` шаблон - https://regex101.com/r/1Sq61J/2 Ну а галочку упомянул, так как в Notepad++ именно она включает данный параметр захвата

Answer (score 1):

Поставите галочку в поле *и новые строки*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно воспользоваться флагом `(?s)` или группой с модификаторм `(?s:...)`:

```
(?s)"=root && .*? ="
"=root && (?s:.*?) ="
```

Comment: у меня не получилось найти с помощью запросов

(?s)"=root && .*? ="
"=root && (?s:.*?) ="
привожу инфу в вопросе

Comment: @vladdv861dvin У вас пробелы вокруг знака `=`, так используйте `=\s*root\s+&&\s+(?s:.*?)\s+=`