# Как заменить текст между тегами?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть `mhtml` страница https://pastebin.com/raw/643TX3Td. Хочу заменить текст между тегами, чтобы он принял вид как обычный html. Думал сперва загрузить все в список, и потом каждое совпадение изменить, но проблема в том что теги в разных строках.

```
var html = File.ReadAllText("1.mhtml");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

var items = Regex.Matches(html, "(?<=>).+?(?=</)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var t = item;
    var newitem = DecodeQuotedPrintables(item, Encoding.UTF8);
    sb.Append(html.Replace(t, newitem));
}
```

Т.е. задача тупо заменить текст между тегами на декодированный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы работаете с HTML через регулярку? Распарсите его и меняйте что надо.

Comment: дело в том что у меня mhtml https://pastebin.com/643TX3Td

Comment: И почему у вас mhtml? Как вы такое получаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать какой-нибудь html-парсер. Например, HtmlAgilityPack.

Вот код с его использованием.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

int start = text.IndexOf("<html>");
int end = text.IndexOf("</html>");
var html = text.Substring(start, end - start + "</html>".Length);

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{
    if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        var trimmed = node.InnerText.Trim();
        if (trimmed.Length > 0)
        {
            var decoded = DecodeQuotedPrintables(trimmed, Encoding.UTF8);
            node.InnerHtml = decoded;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

Функция `DecodeQuotedPrintables` - из вашего предыдущего вопроса.

Сперва отрезал всё до тега `<html>` и после после `</html>`. Возможно, это можно и не делать. После декодирования следует присоединить отрезанные части обратно.

---

Как сделать обработку регуляркой:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
var pattern = "(?<=>).+?(?=</)";
var options = RegexOptions.Singleline;
                        
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => DecodeQuotedPrintables(m.Value, Encoding.UTF8), options);
```

Comment: Только вот `DecodeQuotedPrintables`, на который вы ссылаетесь, дает [белеберду](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipiwr.png) и тут изначально данного вопроса не было бы, если автор понял как работать с mhtml (о чем я написал ему в том вопросе), а этот вопрос явный ведь [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/220553), не?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - да, ваш ответ единственно правильный. А этот вопрос, вероятно, следует закрыть.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы `.` захватывала переводы строк, надо указать флаг `s`.

Например, так:

```
(?s)
```

Подробнее в этом вопросе [Любое количество любых символов в notepad++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1056786/398802).

Comment: Та за шо минус?